# How to resolve collation conflicts with the Entity Framework?

Tags: sql-server, linq, entity-framework, linq-to-entities, collation

My EF model gets data out of a Database that has a view that gets data from a linkedserver. The Collation of the Database in the linkedserver has been changed to SQL_Latin1_General_CP1_CI_AS but not the servers. I am assuming that is where the collation conflict comes from. Every time I do a join with that view I keep getting this error:

> "Cannot resolve the collation conflict between \"SQL_Latin1_General_CP1_CI_AS\"  and\"Modern_Spanish_CI_AS\" in the equal to operation."

I found that collation problems are easily solved in SQL using COLLATE. I can not seem to find a way to do this with LINQ. Can LINQ be used to handle this or should I be tackling this problem in a different way?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

My understanding is that EF does not support this feature.

You can create a new view to resolve the conflict and query the new view with EF.

Comment: If I create a new view, it is still going to be from a server with a non-matching collation.

Comment: I know, but you said in the question "collation problems are easily solved in SQL using COLLATE" - so you should be able to resolve it in the new view ...

Comment: Even if I create a new view using COLLATE on the columns used on joins, it still throws a collation conflict exception

Comment: Have you tried putting the collate on the join part of the query:  table1 t1 join table2 t2 on t1.col COLLATE SQL_Latin1_General_xyz = t2.col

Comment: That should work as long as EF does not have to handle joining data with that view. However, I was using the view so that EF could access data from another server. If I have to write most queries as views or store procs in the database, this in my opinion defeats the purpose of EF. It seems to be me EF is only useful if you have all your data in one database in one server.

Comment: This is really an edge case outside of the remit of an ORM (especially a baby like EF) but I feel your pain. NULLS, dates and character sets are all an Achilles heel for relational databases. In your situation I would be inclined to create a view for each "remote" table, converting it to match the collation of the local database. Let the database handle the character set conflict/resolution as it does do it very well.