# What can I use instead of an Include?

Tags: sql-server, linq, c#-4.0, entity-framework-4.1, ef-model-first

Is there an alternative to using `Include` to eager load entities?

The reason I can't use `Include` is that it *appears* to be case sensitive.
Consider the following example:
I have two tables:

[image]

[image]

Notes the difference in case.

When I want to eager load `Sager`'s `Stamkartotek` I use `Include`, but the `Include` doesn't load `Stamkartotek`:

[image]

** **Update 1** ** 
I noticed this strange behavior - if I *use* any fields from `Stamkartotek` it joins correctly:
[image]

But if I go and only retrieve the value of `Stam_nr` instead of the whole object - it gives me `A` instead of `a`:

[image]

**Research so far:**

- The EF team [knows](http://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/en-US/017fbf0b-eef1-4132-8037-cffc18bea693/include-fails-silently-when-the-case-of-fk-and-pk-do-not-match) about this problem - but have decided not to fix it.
- [This guy](https://stackoverflow.com/q/7421919/1244816) has the same problem only using code-first - no solution has been found

**Update 2**
SQL genereted with `Include`:

```
FROM  [dbo].[Sager] AS [Extent1]
INNER JOIN [dbo].[Stamkartotek] AS [Extent2] ON [Extent1].[Klient_Stam_nr] = [Extent2].[Stam_nr]
WHERE 'jek15' = [Extent1].[Sags_nr]
```

**Update 3**
Loading them in seperate queries, and letting changetracker fixup the reference. It doesn't seem to work either:
[image]

Comment: The MSDN Forum post is old. Did you check whether they fixed it in later versions of EF? If they have, you should upgrade your EF version to the one that fixes the issue. Don't expect fixes to be backported to previous EF versions, especially versions as old as 4.1

Comment: @PanagiotisKanavos I tried building my model using [EF 6.0.1](http://entityframework.codeplex.com/releases/view/112029) but the problem is still there :|

Comment: Then you should probably replace the columns you use for the relationship with ints. The problem isn't in `Include`, it's in the SQL generator when associations use text fields. Using text data for keys is an uncommon practice anyway (for the reasons you just encountered). Or, you could download the EF code (it's OSS) and fix it, if you have the time ...

Comment: @PanagiotisKanavos hmmm the SQL generated looks correct (updated question) but the *mapping* of the result (into CLR classes) that's where I think the problem is.

Comment: @Colin you should add that link to your answer - it is very relevant

Answer (score 3):

Create a view with LOWER around the foreign keys to ensure reads always return the same case to EF.

And do inserts and deletes using stored procedures

You can track and vote for the issue to be addressed here:

[String comparison differences between .NET and SQL Server cause problems for resolving FK relationships in the state manager](https://entityframework.codeplex.com/workitem/284)

Comment: I have no doubt that this suggestion would work - however my question is a gross simplification of my real issue. In my program there are a *lot* of places this would need to be done - so I was hoping for a less "cumbersome" solution

Comment: You get the bounty for pointing me to the official bug rapport - thanks :)

Answer (score 1):

I don't have all the information in this case, I think you have to update the relation of your table using integer keys to make the relation.

When using linq the query is going to execute to the database when you call a ToList() or First for example. If you use an Include, the query will load the data when some of this action is called.

The problem with the A or a can be a collation situation, check your configuration some collation ignore the case of the data.

I propose:
Update the tables you are using with integer keys and use left outer joing if you want to load related data. Sometimes is better to use good old tsql(you can make the left outer join in linq too).

Comment: Thank you for anwsering :) Unfortunally I can't [make EF use collation](http://stackoverflow.com/q/14631035/1244816) becuase it is not supported :| I need EF for changetracking, so I can't handroll the SQL either. Changing the table to use `int` instead of `strings` is a good idea :) but this is the core table of and old system - and I dare not change it :s

Answer (score 1):

Instead of using `.Include` you can load entities in separate queries. Change tracker will fix up relations for related entities it is already tracking and if you get your queries right you should get a solution that from the functional perspective is equivalent to using `.Include`.

Comment: Do I need to do anything else that just loading the entities? I can't get it to work - I have updated my question. (update 3)

Comment: I just tried it and you are right - it won't work. I think this uses the same logic as `.Include` to find relationships. I thought you could 'fix' the keys in the `.ObjectMaterialized` event but it does not work either. Can't you update the data in database so that the casing is the same?

Comment: Thats properly the workaround we have to use. Thank you, for your input